# How to add multiple icons on action bar in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

I want to add 2 or 3 icons on action Bar in android app. I already took the empty activity and added the toolbar. I also set the Icon at left side. Now i want to add another two icons on it. But there is no Menu folder in my project directory structure. So any one tell me how i can do this all with proper guidelines?
My code is here :

My activity file

```
    public class ActionBarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_bar);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.left_nav);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

my .xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="firstapp.vaibhav.com.firstapp.ActionBarActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Screen shot of my project directory structure

Answer (score 26):

**1.** Create a `menu` folder in your existing resource `res` folder. (Ex. `.../res/menu`)

**2.** Create a `main.xml` file in `menu` folder. (Ex. `.../res/menu/main.xml`)

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_item_one"
        android:title="Camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_item_two"
        android:title="Send"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

**3.** In your activity, Override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()` to work with option menus.

**ActionBarActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_camera) {

        // Do something
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_send) {

        // Do something
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 2):

create menu.xml with item like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
   <!-- <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />-->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_autorenew"
        android:title="Search"/>
   <item
       android:id="@+id/action_search"
       android:orderInCategory="100"
       app:showAsAction="always"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
       android:title="Search"/>

</menu>
```

and use it in activity

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
      //  MenuInflater inflater1 = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.cartmenu, menu);
        return ;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

in your res/menu/menu_main.xml:

add

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/icon_id"
        android:visible="true"
        android:title="@string/icon_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/your_image"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    </item>
</menu>
```

in your activity:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    // return true so that the menu pop up is opened
    return true; 
}
```

To access your menu item in `activity` add:

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.your_item_id) {
        // your code
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use showAsAction option found at item in menu resource file.

1) If you want to add popup menu then write `app:showAsAction="never"`

2) If you want to add icons as an action (multiple icons in actionbar) then write `app:showAsAction="always"`

Comment: Thank you, this was the missing piece for me!